# Python pandas dataframe fill NaN with other Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to fill NaN values in a DataFrame (df) column (var4) based on a control table (fillna_mean) using column mean, and var1 as index.In the dataframe I want them to match on var1.

I have tried doing this with fillna but I dont get it to work all the way. How do I do this in a smart way, using df.var1 as index matching fillna_mean.var1?

df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'var1' : list('a' * 3) + list('b' * 2) + list('c' * 4) + list('d' * 3)
         ,'var2' : [i for i in range(12)]
         ,'var3' : list(np.random.randint(100, size = 12))
         ,'var4' : [1, 2, np.nan, 3, 2, np.nan, 1, 34, np.nan, np.nan, 12, 12]
     })
```

fillna_mean:

```
fillna = pd.DataFrame({'var1' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                       'mean' : [1, 3.5, 6.5, 10]})
```

End result is this:

```
var1 var2 var3  var4
a    0    69    1.0
a    1    17    2.0
a    2    83    1.0
b    3    12    3.0
b    4    36    2.0
c    5    68    6.5
c    6    13    1.0
c    7    30    34.0
c    8    23    6.5
d    9    82    10.0
d    10   32    12.0
d    11   19    12.0
```

Thanks in advance for input!

/swepab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) in conjunction with [.map()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) method:

```
In [178]: fillna.set_index('var1', inplace=True)

In [179]: df.loc[df.var4.isnull(), 'var4'] = df.loc[df.var4.isnull(), 'var1'].map(fillna['mean'])

In [180]: df
Out[180]:
   var1  var2  var3  var4
0     a     0    40   1.0
1     a     1    97   2.0
2     a     2    34   1.0
3     b     3     6   3.0
4     b     4    19   2.0
5     c     5    47   6.5
6     c     6    65   1.0
7     c     7    29  34.0
8     c     8    48   6.5
9     d     9    88  10.0
10    d    10    40  12.0
11    d    11    23  12.0
```

Explanation:

```
In [184]: df.loc[df.var4.isnull()]
Out[184]:
  var1  var2  var3  var4
2    a     2    75   NaN
5    c     5    75   NaN
8    c     8    44   NaN
9    d     9    34   NaN

In [185]: df.loc[df.var4.isnull(), 'var1']
Out[185]:
2    a
5    c
8    c
9    d
Name: var1, dtype: object

In [186]: df.loc[df.var4.isnull(), 'var1'].map(fillna['mean'])
Out[186]:
2     1.0
5     6.5
8     6.5
9    10.0
Name: var1, dtype: float64
```

---

**UPDATE:** starting from Pandas 0.20.1 [the .ix indexer is deprecated, in favor of the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix).

Comment: Pure beauty in that one - solid win! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

Get faster results `with combine_first`, and you don't bother you filter out nonnull data:

```
fillna.set_index('var1', inplace=True)

df.var4 = df.var4.combine_first(df.var1.map(fillna['mean']))
```